# Integer 5 equal to 35 in socket communication

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm exchanging some data over socket, and at some point of the communication, I need to send a message like this:

> SendBuff(#$06 + #$05 + Login, Length(Login) + 2);

Exploding the message:

"#$06" = header, I need to send 06 in the front of this message

"#$05" = length for Login, this is the problem in fact!!

"Login" = the AnsiString containing the login

"Length(Login) + 2" = the length of the buffer to be sent, is the length of the login + 2...

Ok, as I said, the problem is in the #$05, if I write this way, it works, the server recognize the message and authorize (considering the length of login is 5). But if I try this way:

> SendBuff(#$06 + IntToStr(Length(Login)) + Login, Length(Login) + 2);

For some reason in fact the socket send the value '35'!!! I tried this:

> SendBuff(#$06 + '5' + Login, Length(Login) + 2);

And same problem, the socket sent the value '35'... What's happening here guys? The SendBuff procedure is receiving parameters this way:

> procedure SendBuff(InputBuff: AnsiString; PacketSize: Integer);

Comment: You should read an ASCII table, that should give a clue.

Comment: I really don't like the way you are building those byte arrays. I think the answer that you accepted at your previous question contains poor advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the ASCII ordinal for the character `5` is 35. When you write:

```
IntToStr(Length(Login))
```

you are converting the integer with value `5` to a string. Which is `'5'`. And `ord('5')` is `35`.

You should use:

```
AnsiChar(Length(Login))
```

and hope that `Login` is never more than 255 characters in length.

Comment: Oh, I didn't saw you answered my last question too... You are like a bot David! Haha.. Thank's for the answer here, and I'll consider now implement your answer for the other question too. Thank you.

Comment: You've rumbled me. I am indeed a bot.